# C# Constructor throwing error

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am writing a program to clean up some database records. I created a GUI to be able to both search the records and to edit them (there are over 100,000 records). I created a Record object with 5 parameters. I also created a Constuctor that takes in those 5 parameters. Yet everytime I build my program, it throws two errors saying "WorkDataCleaner.Record does not contain a constructor that takes 5 arguments".

Here is my Record class and constructor:

```
public class Record
{
    public string[] CatalogNumbers;
    public string CultRegion;
    public string Culture;
    public string[] SiteLocality;
    public string ObjectName;

    /// <summary>
    /// Parameters that builds a Record Object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="CatalogNumbers"></param>
    /// <param name="CultRegion"></param>
    /// <param name="Culture"></param>
    /// <param name="SiteLocality"></param>
    /// <param name="ObjectName"></param>
    public Record(string[] CatalogNumbers, string CultRegion, string Culture, string[] SiteLocality, string ObjectName)
    {
        this.CatalogNumbers = CatalogNumbers;
        this.CultRegion = CultRegion;
        this.Culture = Culture;
        this.SiteLocality = SiteLocality;
        this.ObjectName = ObjectName;
    }


}
```

Here is my code where I call Record (both are throwing errors):

```
string[] CatalogNumbers;
string CultRegion;
string Culture;
string[] SiteLocality;
string ObjectName;
string[] EditsCatNum;
string EditsCReg;
string EditsCult;
string[] EditsSiteLocality;
string EditsObjectName;

Record Search = new Record(CatalogNumbers, CultRegion, Culture, SiteLocality, ObjectName);
Record Edits = new Record(EditsCatNum, EditsCReg, EditsCult, EditsSiteLocality, EditsObjectName);
```

I am calling Record from an event handler of my GUI. I also call Record from a different class outside of my event handlers and it is fine. Whenever I retype the code the errors go away but once i rebuild it, the errors come back. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Are you sure you're not referring to a different type? If you hit "go to declaration" in Visual Studio from the second piece of code, does it take you to the first? (Additionally, I would strongly discourage the use of public fields, and I'd recommend following .NET naming conventions for parameters.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try rebuilding your program? I just copied and pasted your class and the calls to your constructor and didn't get this error.

Comment: I had wondered the same, but he can't rebuild with errors in his program. I'd say the old save and then close and open again. (for future reference this should be a comment when you get 50+ reputation)

Comment: I agree with this post (especially that this should be a comment).

Comment: It was a novice fix...I just cleaned the solution and rebuilt it and it worked. Not a programmer by trade (had to take some programming classes for my major - GIS) thanks for the input everyone.

Comment: This kind of thing gets all of us from time to time. Visual Studio almost kind of puts you to sleep with its ability to seek out bad code in advance, and when it throws errors that shouldn't be there... well, 99.99% of the time they actually are supposed to be there. "What am I doing wrong" is a perfectly logical response.